# The request to open "com.XX.XX" failed The request was denied by service delegate only while using detox

Tags: ios, detox

Detox versions tried : 11.0.0, 12.0.0 & 14.5.1
The app runs fine when we run it via Xcode. The Detox build command succeeds as well.

But when I start running detox tests I will get the following error

```
"/bin/cat /dev/null >/Users/mmoha070/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC24D39E-8290-4314-90F6-685007DBACA8/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out 2>/Users/mmoha070/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AC24D39E-8290-4314-90F6-685007DBACA8/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err && SIMCTL_CHILD_DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="/Users/mmoha070/Library/Detox/ios/34981937206ec401dcf4fd6235cf1a8a3f71e719/Detox.framework/Detox" /usr/bin/xcrun simctl launch --stdout=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.out --stderr=/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.err AC24D39E-8290-4314-90F6-685007DBACA8 com.7ElevenNow.qa.PhoenixiOS --args -detoxServer ws://localhost:53701 -detoxSessionId 34083615-b6f2-86ea-3b33-84b27024f951" failed with code = 1, stdout and stderr:

detox[75658] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] com.7ElevenNow.qa.PhoenixiOS: -1

detox[75658] ERROR: [exec.js/EXEC_FAIL, #6] An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.7ElevenNow.qa.PhoenixiOS" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: Unspecified.
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=1):
The operation couldn’t be completed. (FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain error 1.)
```